# Прерывание программы

Tags: ассемблер, nasm

когда доходит до сюда программа подлагивает и принудительно закрывается.

```
Diver:      
    cmp eax, 4     ;деление
    jne Enave   

        cmp ecx, 0
        jne Next
            mov eax, Stop0
            call print_string
            jmp finish

    Next:
        mov eax, [X]
        mov ebx, [Y]
        div ebx
        mov [Z], eax

        mov eax, Outpromt
        call print_string

        mov eax, [X]
        call print_int

        mov eax, Outpromt1
        call print_string

        mov eax, [Y]
        call print_int

        mov eax, Outpromt6
        call print_string

        mov eax, Outpromt4
        call print_string

        mov eax, [Z]
        call print_int
        
        jmp finish
```

Comment: `div ebx` делит не `eax` на `ebx`, а `edx:eax` на `ebx`. Если `edx` будет не пустым, то в лучшем случае результат будет неправильной, в худшем - переполнение, приводящее к ошибке.

Comment: большое спасибо)